# How to fix influxdb installation if i have another version already?

Tags: windows, influxdb-2

So i initially have influxdb version 2.0.9 in my local windows 11
And i wanted to start fresh, so i deleted my influxdb following someone’s how-to-delete-influxdb (i googled it)

`1 - delete INFLUX.EXE* files from C:\Windows\Prefetch 2 - delete .influxdbv2 folder from C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile 3 - delete any .influxdbv2 folder from my user folders 4 - restart windows`

And yeah i cant access my influxdb anymore, so i installed the newest version 2.7.0… but after i installed it and run it
[image]

Although it shows that, i cant access the web nor ping it via influx or curl

Heres the result to influx health for config toward my influxdb server

`Get "http://localhost:8086/health": wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

I did try to re install the 2.0.9 version but it didnt work too, it might have been something that i deleted but i cant restore the file that i deleted, so im stuck right now ;-;